# Chandelier came apart after removing bulb

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, hanging

The light bulb in the center of my dining area chandelier (I assume this is what it's called, it's a hanging lamp) went out. I unscrewed the bulb, removed it, and the lamp itself came unscrewed. I attempted to screw it back together, but it doesn't hold.

I can't see a way to take it down easily, if anyone can help me figure a way forward to having a functional light fixture again I would greatly appreciate it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

[Here are some photos.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzMPa.jpg)

Comment: I tried to edit your post to move the images into the post itself rather than through a link, but they are too large.  Perhaps you could resize them and reupload.

Comment: I apologize, I am on mobile. I will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiring to the lamps run through threaded bushes. The wiring to the central bush has an earthed washer flapping in mid-air currently doing nothing.

It looks as though the central threaded bush screws up into the substantial angle bracket visible in your second picture above. That would trap the washer against the lower part of the chandelier and hence provide it with a protective earth connection.

So feed the central bush up into the angle bracket and turn it to fasten. Make sure no wires get stuck between the bracket and the central threaded bush.

From your additional pictures it looks as though there isn't a deep thread on the hole through the angle bracket. Some loctite might help, sparingly applied to the thread on the bush. Don't get it over the loose washer or you'll lose your protective earthing.

If you want to remove the chandelier there are guides on the Internet. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdkdCJJN4zM) seems logical (though it's not my continent).

If you remove it I suggest:

1. Switch off the lighting circuit at the breaker, not just the light switch, (and still check the circuit is dead, as shown in the video).
2. Be prepared to take the full weight of the chandelier at any time as you loosen it. A second person to support it as you undo the fastening will help, as will removing any detachable parts first to save weight.

Here's the classic British [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFuYIi5-igc) on how not to remove a chandelier.

Comment: the video actually helped quite a bit to clarify exactly how to take down the fixture. The chandelier in the video has an almost identical mount. I will have to wait for help to take it down but it appears to be the only way to get this back together. Thank you so much for the answer and links.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the locknuts on that central threaded rod were loose and the act of unscrewing the bulb caused that rod to turn as well, unscrewing it from the collar in the upper part of the fixture.

To fix it, look for the other end of that threaded rod in the lower part of the fixture, and thread it back into the upper.  Once it is tight, there should be a thin nut facing you as you look up that can be tightened.  Tighten that up as much as you can to keep the rod from spinning when you change the bulb next time.

Comment: I have been trying this since you posted and it just spins. It doesn't seem to catch either way I rotate the lower part with the socket into what appears to be the female side. Guess I will need to figure out how to take this down, it came with the condo and there's no manual, nor can I find a part number or branding